# after log4j upgradation kafka unable to start

Tags: apache-kafka, log4j, apache-zookeeper

I have recently updated the logging jar of our application from log4j-1.2.17.jar to the latest log4j-1.2-api-2.18.0.jar.After configuring the latest .my kafka server and zookeeper server unable to start

```
log4j-1.2-api-2.16.0.jar
log4j-api-2.16.0.jar
log4j-core-2.16.0.jar
log4j-slf4j-impl-2.16.0.jar
slf4j-api-1.7.30.jar
```

how to resolve this issue after update the log4j

Answer (score 0):

You cannot just upgrade JARs and hope things will work. Instead, upgrade all of Kafka and Zookeeper, as I believe they both use reload4j now.

- https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-13660
- https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ZOOKEEPER-4626